# Move Android Sources to another Machine

Tags: android, synchronization, repo

So, Basically I've synced all the Cm-11.0 sources to my PC. Now I had move the sources to another PC. So i thought that copying just '.repo' folder and running repo sync -l to another PC will do the trick. 
Now I have .repo folder and when I run repo sync it gives the following error

```
dkbhadeshiya@CrayJaguar:~/android/cm11$ repo sync -j1
Fetching project CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_webview
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dkbhadeshiya/android/cm11/.repo/repo/main.py", line 500, in <module>
    _Main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/dkbhadeshiya/android/cm11/.repo/repo/main.py", line 476, in _Main
    result = repo._Run(argv) or 0
  File "/home/dkbhadeshiya/android/cm11/.repo/repo/main.py", line 155, in _Run
    result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
  File "/home/dkbhadeshiya/android/cm11/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 635, in Execute
    fetched = self._Fetch(to_fetch, opt)
  File "/home/dkbhadeshiya/android/cm11/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 339, in _Fetch
    self._FetchProjectList(**kwargs)
  File "/home/dkbhadeshiya/android/cm11/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 234, in _FetchProjectList
    success = self._FetchHelper(opt, project, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dkbhadeshiya/android/cm11/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 275, in _FetchHelper
    no_tags=opt.no_tags, archive=self.manifest.IsArchive)
  File "/home/dkbhadeshiya/android/cm11/.repo/repo/project.py", line 1076, in Sync_NetworkHalf
    self._UpdateHooks()
  File "/home/dkbhadeshiya/android/cm11/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2098, in _UpdateHooks
    self._InitHooks()
  File "/home/dkbhadeshiya/android/cm11/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2126, in _InitHooks
    os.symlink(os.path.relpath(stock_hook, os.path.dirname(dst)), dst)
OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory
```

and when I run Repo Sync -l It gives following error:

```
dkbhadeshiya@CrayJaguar:~/android/cm11$ repo sync -l
error: in `sync -l`: revision refs/heads/cm-11.0 in CyanogenMod/android_abi_cpp not found
```

Any Idea how to solve this??

Comment: If you have a repo, there's no need to copy them.  You should just synch from the old machine and check it out on the new machine from the same location.  Manual moving is not a suggested practice, but certainly could be done.

Comment: How did you move the sources ?
In case if you copied your .repo folder to a NTFS/FAT32 drive, then all your efforts will be in vain.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this command before you sync.

```
repo forall -vc "git reset --hard"
```